# data.table with two string columns of set elements, extract unique rows with each row unsorted

Tags: r, duplicates, set, data.table, unique

Suppose I have a data.table like this:

Table:

```
V1 V2
 A  B
 C  D
 C  A
 B  A
 D  C
```

I want each row to be regarded as a set, which means that B A and A B are the same. So after the process, I want to get:

```
V1 V2
 A  B
 C  D
 C  A
```

In order to do that, I have to first **sort the table row-by-row** and then use `unique` to remove the duplicates. The sorting process is quite slow if I have millions of rows. So is there an easy way to remove the duplicates without sorting?

Comment: Do you have only two columns?

Comment: @eddi Currently yes. Does that matter?

Comment: Multiple string data.table columns are not a great way to denote set membership, I'd use a bitfield, that can handle 32 elements. What are you ultimately trying to do with the rows, after this operation?

Answer (score 18):

For just two columns you can use the following trick:

```
dt = data.table(a = letters[1:5], b = letters[5:1])
#   a b
#1: a e
#2: b d
#3: c c
#4: d b
#5: e a

dt[dt[, .I[1], by = list(pmin(a, b), pmax(a, b))]$V1]
#   a b
#1: a e
#2: b d
#3: c c
```

Answer (score 3):

Borrowing (probably unrealistic) data from [a dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55710990/1191259):

```
library(data.table)
size <- 118000000
key1 <- sample( LETTERS, size, replace=TRUE, prob=runif(length(LETTERS), 0.0, 5.0) )
key2 <- sample( LETTERS, size, replace=TRUE, prob=runif(length(LETTERS), 0.0, 5.0) )
val <- runif(size, 0.0, 5.0)

dt <- data.table(key1, key2, val, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Here's a fast way if your data looks like this:

```
# eddi's answer
system.time(res1 <- dt[dt[, .I[1], by=.(pmin(key1, key2), pmax(key1, key2))]$V1])
#    user  system elapsed 
#  101.79    3.01  107.98 

# optimized for this data
system.time({
  dt2 <- unique(dt, by=c("key1", "key2"))[key1 > key2, c("key1", "key2") := .(key2, key1)]
  res2 <- unique(dt2, by=c("key1", "key2")) 
})
#    user  system elapsed 
#    8.50    1.16    4.93 

fsetequal(copy(res1)[key1 > key2, c("key1", "key2") := .(key2, key1)], res2)
# [1] TRUE
```

Data like this seems unlikely if it pertains to covariances, since you should have at most one duplicate (ie, A-B with B-A).

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
df[!duplicated(t(apply(df, 1, sort))), ]
```

where `df` is your dataframe

Answer (score -1):

Here is the simple way of removing duplicate rows.

```
delRows = NULL # the rows to be removed
for(i in 1:nrow(tab)){
  j = which(tab$V1 == tab$V2[i] & tab$V2 == tab$V1[i])
  j = j [j > i]
  if (length(j) > 0){
    delRows = c(delRows, j)
  }
}
tab = tab[-delRows,]
```

The result is,
Before,

```
> tab
  V1 V2
1  A  B
2  C  D
3  C  A
4  B  A
5  D  C
```

After,

```
> tab
  V1 V2
1  A  B
2  C  D
3  C  A
```