# pair-wise duplicate removal from dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates

This seems like a simple problem but I can't seem to figure it out. I'd like to remove duplicates from a dataframe (df) if two columns have the same values, even if those values are in the **reverse order**. What I mean is, say you have the following data frame:

```
a <- c(rep("A", 3), rep("B", 3), rep("C",2))
b <- c('A','B','B','C','A','A','B','B')
df <-data.frame(a,b)

  a b
1 A A
2 A B
3 A B
4 B C
5 B A
6 B A
7 C B
8 C B
```

If I now remove duplicates, I get the following data frame:

```
df[duplicated(df),]

  a b
3 A B
6 B A
8 C B
```

However, I would also like to remove the row 6 in this data frame, since "A", "B" is the same as "B", "A". How can I do this automatically?

Ideally I could specify which two columns to compare since the data frames could have varying columns and can be quite large.

Thanks!

Comment: an almost duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/25145982/817778 - only difference being if you for some reason want to stay within `data.frame` (unlikely, especially given you say your data is large, but who knows)

Comment: You're not removing duplicates with your current code, you're keeping duplicates.

Comment: What I mean by removing duplicate is simply keeping a single occurrence of a repeated pattern across two columns and that is what I in fact am doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution is to first sort each row of `df`:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df))
{
    df[i, ] = sort(df[i, ])
}
df

a b
1 A A
2 A B
3 A B
4 B C
5 A B
6 A B
7 B C
8 B C
```

At that point it's just a matter of removing the duplicated elements:

```
df = df[!duplicated(df),]
df
  a b 
1 A A
2 A B
4 B C
```

As thelatemail mentioned in the comments, your code actualy *keeps* the duplicates. You need to use `!duplicated` to remove them.

Comment: Ari, you've been so helpful with R-related questions. Thanks for your help!

Comment: The OP says, "Ideally I could specify which two columns to compare since the data frames could have varying columns and can be quite large." I don't see that being addressed in this solution.

Answer (score 8):

Extending Ari's answer, to specify columns to check if other columns are also there:

```
a <- c(rep("A", 3), rep("B", 3), rep("C",2))
b <- c('A','B','B','C','A','A','B','B')
df <-data.frame(a,b)

df$c = sample(1:10,8)
df$d = sample(LETTERS,8)
df
  a b  c d
1 A A 10 B
2 A B  8 S
3 A B  7 J
4 B C  3 Q
5 B A  2 I
6 B A  6 U
7 C B  4 L
8 C B  5 V

cols = c(1,2)
newdf = df[,cols]
for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
    newdf[i, ] = sort(df[i,cols])
}

df[!duplicated(newdf),]
  a b c d
1 A A 8 X
2 A B 7 L
4 B C 2 P
```

Comment: This is the only answer that addresses the full request of the OP

Answer (score 4):

The other answers use a `for` loop to assign a value for each and every row. While this is not an issue if you have 100 rows, or even a thousand, you're going to be waiting a while if you have large data of the order of 1M rows.

Stealing from the [other linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25151395/496803) using `data.table`, you could try something like:

```
df[!duplicated(data.frame(list(do.call(pmin,df),do.call(pmax,df)))),]
```

A comparison benchmark with a larger dataset (`df2`):

```
df2 <- df[sample(1:nrow(df),50000,replace=TRUE),]

system.time(
  df2[!duplicated(data.frame(list(do.call(pmin,df2),do.call(pmax,df2)))),]
)
# user  system elapsed 
# 0.07    0.00    0.06 

system.time({
  for (i in 1:nrow(df2))
  {
      df2[i, ] = sort(df2[i, ])
  }
  df2[!duplicated(df2),]
}
)
#   user  system elapsed 
#  42.07    0.02   42.09
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `apply` will be a better option than loops.

```
newDf <- data.frame(t(apply(df,1,sort)))
```

All you need to do now is remove duplicates.

```
newDf <- newDf[!duplicated(newDf),]
```

Comment: Apply is a great utility. But I think this code will need to be modified if more than 2 concerned columns are there which also need to be maintained.