# Aggregating Rows Based on Strings in different orders

Tags: r, merge, row, col

I have a dataset, a sample of which can be represented by the below:

```
    ORIGIN <- c("SFO", "BOS", "LAX", "BOS")
    DEST <- c("BOS", "SFO", "BOS", "LAX")
    PASS<- c(100,50,20,40)
    df = data.frame(ORIGIN, DEST, ROUTE, PASS)

ORIGIN DEST    PASS
SFO    BOS     100
BOS    SFO     50
LAX    BOS     20
BOS    LAX     40
```

I'm trying to combine ORIGIN and DEST together to form ROUTE, and then aggregate the rows by route, without regard to the origin or destination, to get total passenger numbers.

Ideally I would like the below:

```
ROUTE    PASS
SFO-BOS  150
LAX-BOS  60
```

I don't care about which route naming metric prevails, as long as I can combine them.

As a first step, I've used this:

```
df$ROUTE<-paste(df$ORIGIN, df$DEST, sep="-")
```

To get the below:

```
ORIGIN DEST   ROUTE    PASS
SFO    BOS    SFO-BOS  100
BOS    SFO    BOS-SFO  50
LAX    BOS    LAX-BOS  20
BOS    LAX    BOS-LAX  40
```

However while I would usually use something like ddply to get the passenger sum, I'm unsure of how to proceed since I'm trying to combine "BOS-SFO" and "SFO-BOS".

This would not be an issue in a small file, but the file I'm working with is excessively large.

Would someone be able to help?

Comment: Relevant - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35834385/create-unique-identifier-from-the-interchangeable-combination-of-two-variables/35834584 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25297812/pair-wise-duplicate-removal-from-dataframe/25298863 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25145982/extract-unique-rows-from-a-data-table-with-each-row-unsorted/25151395

Comment: Your `paste()` can still work, but you need to sort the route first, `paste(apply(df[,1:2],1,max),apply(df[,1:2],1,min),sep="-") ` Then you can simply aggregate by route `aggregate(PASS ~ ROUTE, data=df, sum)`

Answer (score 1):

This is what `pmax` and `pmin` are for. Using `dplyr`:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(start = pmin(ORIGIN, DEST),
         end = pmax(ORIGIN, DEST)) %>% 
  group_by(start, end) %>% 
  summarize(PASS = sum(PASS))

#  start   end  PASS
# 1   BOS   LAX    60
# 2   BOS   SFO   150
```

Comment: Yep. Base translation - `df$ROUTE <- interaction(do.call(pmin, lapply(df[c("ORIGIN","DEST")],as.character)), do.call(pmax, lapply(df[c("ORIGIN","DEST")],as.character)))` and `aggregate(PASS ~ ROUTE, data=df, sum)`

Answer (score 0):

Using `mapply` in base R to combine the results,

```
# sort each pair of dest and origin by row and paste results.
df$ROUTE <- mapply(function(x, y) paste(sort(c(x, y)), collapse="-"),
                   df$ORIGIN, df$DEST, USE.NAMES=FALSE)

aggregate(PASS ~ ROUTE, data=df, sum)
    ROUTE PASS
1 BOS-LAX   60
2 BOS-SFO  150
```

**data**

Note that this method requires working with character variables rather than factor variables. The data.frame, df, is constructed as below.

```
df = data.frame(ORIGIN, DEST, PASS, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```