# Get unique rows based on order independent combination of columns - data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Here is an example of what I am trying to achieve. Consider the following `data.table` -

```
library(data.table)
x <- data.table(
  Org = c('BNE', 'SIN', 'ADL', 'SIN', 'SYD', 'MEL', 'BNE'), 
  Dest = c('ADL', 'MEL', 'SYD', 'BNE', 'ADL', 'SIN', 'ADL')
)
> x
   Org Dest
1: BNE  ADL
2: SIN  MEL
3: ADL  SYD
4: SIN  BNE
5: SYD  ADL
6: MEL  SIN
7: BNE  ADL
```

I am trying to get to the following table -

```
   Org Dest
1: BNE  ADL
2: SIN  MEL
3: ADL  SYD
4: SIN  BNE
```

In `x`, for my use case, row 1 and 7, row 2 and 6, and row 3 and 5 are duplicates. i.e. the order of the columns within the de-duplicating columns does not matter and MEL-SIN is the same SIN-MEL.

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9028369/removing-duplicate-combinations-irrespective-of-order), but that questions considers matrices which makes the use of `apply` functions possible, which may not be economical given that I have a large `data.table` of ~35M rows.

What might be the fastest way to go from `x` to the bottom `data.table`?

Comment: Some useful links - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46943753/r-data-table-duplicate-rows-with-a-pair-of-columns/46944062 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25145982/extract-unique-rows-from-a-data-table-with-each-row-unsorted/25151395#25151395